# JavaFX - generate compile time error if a class doesn't exist in css

Tags: css, eclipse, javafx, preprocessor

I develop an application in JavaFX. Now i've got the Problem that i would like to generate an error at compile time if a css class, e.g. for a button, which if've set in the code doesn't exist in the corresponding css file.

**Example:**

**main.java**

```
        String sCSS = this.getClass().getResource("/main.css").toExternalForm();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(sCSS);
        Button btn = new Button("Hello JFXWorld...");
        btn.getStyleClass().add("button"); // should show compile time error
```

**main.css**

```
.buttonWithWrongName {
-fx-background-color: red; }
```

My solution would be the following, but I'm looking for advice how I can realize it.

I include an preprocessor or create an new project or something like that which parses the css code and dynamically generates an enum (into a .jar). And this jar i could include into my Project. In the best case ant would trigger the build of the enum automatically if no preprocessor is used.

again an **Example**:

*Css file is the same as above.*

{
 Do preprocessor stuff for the css file here (parse and create enum) and build it to a jar file.
}

**main.java**

```
        String sCSS = this.getClass().getResource("/main.css").toExternalForm();
                    scene.getStylesheets().add(sCSS);
                    Button btn = new Button("Hello JFXWorld...");
// will throw an compile time error becaus the eMainCSS enum only contains the class ".buttonWithWrongName" 
                    btn.getStyleClass().add(eMainCSS.button.toString()); 

 // works fine 
          btn.getStyleClass().add(eMainCSS.buttonWithWrongName.toString());
```

I'm using Eclipse (Neon) and JDK 1.8.0. 
I hope there's a solution.

Thank you for the answers.

Best Regards,

Max S.

---

**-- Edit --**

### **Solution:**

I've used an [Ant WatchTask](https://github.com/chubbard/WatchTask) to watch at all my less files in the project.
If I change something in the less file, ant will run a self written jar file with the file name as parameter. The jar converts the less file to a css file  (with [less4j](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j)) and the css file to a java file (my own parser) which contains the enum.

**Note:** You`re not allowed to change anything in the enum. Even if you do, after the next changes in the less file, it`ll be gone.

**The result looks like this:**

*Stylesheet.less:*

```
.button { -fx-stroke-width: (1 + 1); }
#anotherButton { -fx-stroke-width: (1 + 2); }
```

to *Stylesheet.css:*

```
.button { -fx-stroke-width: 2; }
#anotherButton { -fx-stroke-width: 3; }
```

to *Stylesheet.java:*

```
  // Auto-generated java file

  public enum Stylesheet {

  C_BUTTON("button"),
  ID_ANOTHERBUTTON("anotherButton");

  private final String sValue;

  Stylesheet(String sValue) {
       this.sValue = sValue;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
       return this.sValue;
  }
```

}

Now the compiler will throw an error at the compile time if the class or id which i'm using in javafx doesn`t exist.

Best Regards,

Max S.

Comment: That is a pretty bad idea. Let's assume you use a enum constant that contains a correct style class. Then you modify the enum and change the string to a incorrect one. Now all classes using the enum constant should yield a compile time error, but they are not even recompiled so how should the compiler know about them? And then you modify the CSS file. The compiler does not even run in this case... Better annotate the enum and use a annotation processor to create data for a test suite checking the CSS...

Comment: And you seem to be assuming that the location of the CSS file can always be determined at compile time... What if it is, e.g., retrieved from user preferences or a property file/

Comment: @fabian - I'll use ant to check if changes were made in my Project stucture for css/less files. Then ant will Trigger the conversion from less to css and from the css to enum. And I'll never modify the enum by myself, it's auto generated. The only file i'll modify will be the less file. I've already found a working solution. I will post it in about 8 hours, after work....

Comment: @James_D - Even in this case the buttons need to "know" the classes / ids which they are assigned to, so the user defined css stylesheet class or ids names must follow the "original" one. Otherwise it wouldn't make any sense to define classes. The enum will be automatically generated before the root Project is build, so the names will match. Independent from the used css file.